# Media Queries issue: Safari not scaling elements in REM

Tags: html, css, safari, media-queries, mobile-safari

My layout is rem based and recently I noticed, that Safari (Desktop and mobile) only scales font-sizes, but no other elements. 
Specifically, it scales elements with the first media query.

Everything works just fine in Chrome and Firefox.

HTML

```
<h1>Hello Circle</h1>
<div class="circle"></div>
```

CSS

```
html,
body {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  background-color: red;
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  html,
  body {
    font-size: 50%;
    background-color: green;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 579px) {
  html,
  body {
    font-size: 30%;
    background-color: blue;
  }
}

.circle {
  width: 20rem;
  height: 20rem;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ew97d4rj (The yellow circle is supposed to get smaller with every MQ – like the text – but in Safari the circle is not shrinking in the smallest MQ.)

I guess there is something wrong with the Media Queries, because if I use the MQs below, it works, but breaks my layout since the normal sizes are used only between 579px and 700px.

```
html,
body {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  background-color: red;
}

@media (max-width: 579px) {
  html,
  body {
    font-size: 30%;
    background-color: green;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  html,
  body {
    font-size: 90%;
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am now pretty sure, that it is an **Safari minimal font-size issue** and has nothing to do with the media queries. If I use media queries with 200%/150/100% fontsize, it works just "fine". 
When I search for a solution, I find the solution to use `-webkit-text-size-adjust: none`, but it seems to be no longer supported. At least, it has no effect.
Also, my assumption was that text scales as supposed, was wrong. It just scales the Safari set minimum font size.

*I use Safari 10.1 on my machine and Safari 11 on my phone.*

Answer (score 0):

use meta in head tag. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

and than use css media queries like this and font-size apply only on body tag not html
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px){

```
body {
    font-size: 50%;
    background-color: green;
  }
```

}

Comment: Not sure if I should use html for the non-MQ declaration? If I don't, it is not scaling at all: http://jsfiddle.net/ew97d4rj/8/

Comment: I am using the  `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0">`  tag and it doesn't make a difference to leave the `maximum-scale` out.

Comment: first you do not use body tag and media query in very last your css file 
and use your div .circle in media query

Comment: Thank you, that works. But it's not exactly what I was looking for, since it requires rewriting almost every element which results in 3x more code in some of my use cases. And that's not really an option. So I'm still looking for a MQ based solution.