# Setting root font-size not affecting rem units in Safari for margin, padding, etc

Tags: css, safari

I have an web application which renders perfectly in Chrome and Firefox but looks completely incomprehensible in Safari. I believe this is due to how Safari handles rem units for padding, the magin, and so on.

I set the font-size in `html` and `root` within my CSS to `6.25%`, which, given the default font-size of `16px`, translates the `rem` scaler to be `1px` (i.e. `10rem` becomes `10px`). I then specify all sizes with `rem` units. I did this due to a few resources online suggesting this to be a good strategy, and it had served me very well so far.

However, in Safari (14.1.2, and almost certainly before, I'd never tested on Safari) it appears to only scale the font-size. All padding, margins, and so on are actually 9 times bigger than they should be. For example, I specify a margin to be `14rem 16rem 14rem 16rem` and Safari will render it as `126px 144px 126px 144px`, which scales everything up massively and makes the page unviewable. However, the font size is accurate.

Setting `margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px` and so on in my `html` CSS class doesn't seem to have worked.

How do I best fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe that's some trouble with Safari setting minimum font sizes. Safari does not allow fonts to be "too small", so I guess your scaling does not work as expected in Safari.

This was discussed here:
[Media Queries issue: Safari not scaling elements in REM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52001765/media-queries-issue-safari-not-scaling-elements-in-rem)

Comment: You're right... If I set the base `font-size` to `10px` and then use `rem` at x0.1 what I currently have now it all works... _Why, Apple... Why..?_ This also explains why it's `x9`; perhaps `9px` is the smallest `font-size` they're happy with. I'll play around a little more to make sure this covers it, before marking your answer as correct.

Comment: One thing I don't understand is why it left the sizes of my fonts as they should be but didn't leave the margin and border sizes (etc.) as they should be. Youi'd think it'd be all or nothing, if this is the case.

Comment: Well, I think it didn't but scaled the font size "back" :D

Comment: Perhaps... in any case, it's indeed all working now, thank you for your answer!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: FWIW you can also use 1px and avoid scaling your rem values, Safari will apply a "smart minimum" to fonts that scale to under 9px but not if you explicitly specify a value in px. See https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/blob/7f27a00f1eb14a39e730336e96b639d852d322f3/Source/WebCore/style/StyleFontSizeFunctions.cpp#L59